# On iOS 9 RequestImageForAsset returns small image retrieving 1:1 photos with filters

Tags: ios, ios9, photosframework, phasset

as the question states, I am getting a 120x120 image if I do RequestImageForAsset on any device running iOS 9 or greater (tried on iPhone 5s, 6, and 6s Plus) when I try to retrieve a picture taken with 1:1 option AND filters. Notice that this doesn't happen if the Picture is 1:1 without filters or standard with filters, but just when the two options have been applied to a picture at the same time. 
I tried to tamper with the PHImageRequestOptions (especially with the resize mode, e.g. setting it to none) but the retrieved image is still 120x120...
Anybody else has run into this and has a solution to get the full resolution image?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add **QualityFormat** with **PHImageRequestOptions**. you will get full resolution image.

```
PHImageRequestOptions* options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init]; 
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:node.asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
      //Write your code here
}];
```

Hope you will get solution from this.

Comment: for me it worked fine, I was using Xcode 11 / iOS 13.xx